# Which country code format does Apple use when it sends in-app purchase requests to our server?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Apple sends the country, currency, location, price and a lot of other information for an in-app purchase. Which 2 letter country code system does it use for these purchases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple actually doesn't include any of that information in an [SKPaymentTransaction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransaction?language=swift). They do include the price and price locale in the [SKProduct](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproduct?language=swift) object - the [NSLocale](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale?language=swift) of the price contains a [countryCode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1643060-countrycode?language=objc) property that is the two-letter country string. e.g. "GB", "FR", "HK", etc.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know which ISO format is the country code in?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it's documented but looks like `ISO 3166-1 alpha-2`